# Best way to check each productId in order and if there is same productId add there quantity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I need a best solution to loop through each order item and if there is two product Id matches then add there quantity:

```
 var order = [
{
    "coupon": {},
    "billingAddress": {},
    "shippingAddress": {},
    "_id": "1234567890s4s5s3",
    "userId": 125,
    "subtotal": 15208,
    "shipping": null,
    "tax": 192,
    "total": 7700,
    "status": "confirmed",
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
            "productTitle": "iPhone",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 3104,
            "tax": 96,
            "subtotal": 3104
        },
        {
            "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
            "productTitle": "Iphone",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 3104,
            "tax": 96,
            "subtotal": 3104
        },
        {
            "productId": "5fc0b9646ce7332838122784",
            "productTitle": "Tv",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 4500,
            "subtotal": 4500,
            "tax": 0
        },
        {
            "productId": "5fc0b9646ce7332838122784",
            "productTitle": "Tv",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 4500,
            "subtotal": 4500,
            "tax": 0
        }
    ],

    "shipmentTracking": [
        {}
    ],
    "siteId": "5f3799e12c6291446ea8c75f",
},
{
    "billingAddress": {},
    "shippingAddress": {},
    "_id": "5f9d5bead92083a9810d526c",
    "status": "confirmed",
    "userId": 125,
    "subtotal": 121.25,
    "shipping": 5,
    "total": 130,
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
            "productTitle": "Iphone",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 121.25,
            "subtotal": 121.25,
            "shipping": 5,
            "tax": 3.75
        }
    ],
    "siteId": "5f3799e12c6291446ea8c75f",

}]
```

Please look the above code in this condition how can you get output like:

data:[{
productId:5fc0b9646ce7332838122784,
productName:Tv,
totalQuantity:2,
totalSaleAmount:--

},{product 2 details
}]

Answer (score 1):

Use one `forEach` loop and track the items and increment quantity for same product. Use `Object.values` from the tracking object (result).

```js
const updateItems = (arr) => {
  const result = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    result[item.productId] ??= { ...item, quantity: 0 };
    result[item.productId].quantity += 1;
  });
  return Object.values(result);
};

var order = [
  {
    orderId: "12345678912345gh",
    shippingAddress: {},
    billingAddress: {},
    orderItems: [
      {
        productId: "234567890qwe3456",
        productTitle: "iphone",
        quantity: 1,
        price: 40000,
      },
      {
        productId: "234567890qwe3116",
        productTitle: "pan",
        quantity: "1",
        price: 20000,
      },
      {
        productId: "234567890qwe3456",
        productTitle: "iphone",
        quantity: 1,
        price: 40000,
      },
      {
        productId: "234567890qwe3avc",
        productTitle: "vohone",
        quantity: 1,
        price: 40000,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const output = order.map(({orderItems, ...item}) => ({
  ...item,
  orderItems: updateItems(orderItems),
}));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for (let i = 0 ; i < order.length ; i++ ) {
    for (let j = i+1 ; j < order.length ; j++ ) {
        if (order[i].productId == order[j].productId)
            // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do any thing you want in `your code` section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Extract the order items to separate array and compute the total quantity and total sale amount . Refer below code

```js
var order = [
  {
      "coupon": {},
      "billingAddress": {},
      "shippingAddress": {},
      "_id": "1234567890s4s5s3",
      "userId": 125,
      "subtotal": 15208,
      "shipping": null,
      "tax": 192,
      "total": 7700,
      "status": "confirmed",
      "orderItems": [
          {
              "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
              "productTitle": "iPhone",
              "quantity": 1,
              "price": 3104,
              "tax": 96,
              "subtotal": 3104
          },
          {
              "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
              "productTitle": "Iphone",
              "quantity": 1,
              "price": 3104,
              "tax": 96,
              "subtotal": 3104
          },
          {
              "productId": "5fc0b9646ce7332838122784",
              "productTitle": "Tv",
              "quantity": 1,
              "price": 4500,
              "subtotal": 4500,
              "tax": 0
          },
          {
              "productId": "5fc0b9646ce7332838122784",
              "productTitle": "Tv",
              "quantity": 1,
              "price": 4500,
              "subtotal": 4500,
              "tax": 0
          }
      ],
  
      "shipmentTracking": [
          {}
      ],
      "siteId": "5f3799e12c6291446ea8c75f",
  },
  {
      "billingAddress": {},
      "shippingAddress": {},
      "_id": "5f9d5bead92083a9810d526c",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "userId": 125,
      "subtotal": 121.25,
      "shipping": 5,
      "total": 130,
      "orderItems": [
          {
              "productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5",
              "productTitle": "Iphone",
              "quantity": 1,
              "price": 121.25,
              "subtotal": 121.25,
              "shipping": 5,
              "tax": 3.75
          }
      ],
      "siteId": "5f3799e12c6291446ea8c75f",
  
  }]

    //reducer function to be used to eztract order items
    const reducer = (accumulator=[],currentValue) => {
      if(currentValue.orderItems && currentValue.orderItems.length > 0){
        const extractedItems = currentValue.orderItems.map(item => {
          return {quantity:item.quantity ,productTitle:item.productTitle, price:item.price , productId:item.productId}
        })
  
        return accumulator.concat(extractedItems)
      }
    }

  //extracting order items
  const orederItems = order.reduce(reducer , [])


  
 // data which stores product ids as keys
  const data = {};

  //loop over extracted order items and populate data with totalSaleAmt and totalQty
  orederItems.forEach(item => {
    
    const currentQty = data[item.productId] && data[item.productId]["totalQty"] ? data[item.productId]["totalQty"]:0;
    const currentTotalSaleAmt = data[item.productId] && data[item.productId]["totalSaleAmt"] ? data[item.productId]["totalSaleAmt"]:0;
    data[item.productId] = {
      
      title:item.productTitle,
      totalQty:currentQty + item.quantity,
      totalSaleAmt:currentTotalSaleAmt + item.price
    }
    
  });

  //data will hold the required information
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hi @DeepakTomson can make the output like arry of objects? example: [ {"productId": "5f44eb9a491a455bc6de2de5", "title": "2L MagicPot Neo", "totalQuantity": "2L MagicPot Neo", "totalSaleAmount": 6329.25},{ "productId": "5fc0b9646ce7332838122784", "title": "test", "totalQuantity": "test", "totalSaleAmount": 9000}]

Comment: //use below after getting data object
 // converting to final required array
  const finalData = Object.keys(data).map(dataItem => {
    return {
     ...data[dataItem]
    }
  })

 //finalData will hold the required information
  console.log(finalData)

Comment: Yes!@ DeepakTomson